# how can I use like query in ruby with sinatra?

Tags: ruby, activerecord, sinatra

Here's the query I tried:

```
@blogs = DB[:blogs].where(:title => params[:s_txt]).reverse_order(:id)
```

In this query, I'd like to find blogs in my database. I also need to create a query that gives users more results. How can I do this?

Comment: What does this have to do with Sinatra?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also had this problem and only found this solution

```
@blogs = DB[:blogs].where("title LIKE '%#{params[:s_txt]}%'").reverse_order(:id)
```

Curious if there are better ways..

Searching in two fields is repeating the LIKE and seperating by AND or OR

```
@blogs = DB[:blogs].where("title LIKE '%#{params[:s_txt]}%' 
  or comment LIKE '%#{params[:c_txt]}%'").reverse_order(:id)
```

or do it like this

```
@blogs = DB[:blogs].where("title||comment LIKE '%#{params[:s_txt]}%'").reverse_order(:id)
```

Tested in Sqlite and it works. One advise: in lage tables you 'd better drop the first % if possible because the database will do a full table scan otherwise without using indexes but you can find all that stuff in the sql questions.

Comment: `"title LIKE '%?%'", params[:s_txt]` would be preferred.

Comment: thanks for your answer and that's good and work :) , but how can I search by two col like title and content ?

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use [dynamic parameters](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#class-ActiveRecord%3a%3aBase-label-Conditions) to avoid SQL injection:

```
@blogs = DB[:blogs].where("title LIKE ?", "%#{params[:s_txt]}%").reverse_order(:id)
```

or

```
@blogs = DB[:blogs].where("title LIKE :text", text: "%#{params[:s_txt]}%").reverse_order(:id)
```

You can easily add more parameters to this:

```
@blogs = DB[:blogs].where("title LIKE ? OR content LIKE ?", "%#{params[:s_txt]}%", "%#{params[:s_txt]}%").reverse_order(:id)
```

or

```
@blogs = DB[:blogs].where("title LIKE :text OR content LIKE :text", text: "%#{params[:s_txt]}%").reverse_order(:id)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer and that's good and work :) , but how can I search by two col like title and content ?

Comment: @AliOsm i use neither of them for chatting (oldfashioned I know), I have limited experience in using Qt and QtRuby (green_shoes guy) and none with the combination QtCreator, i'm exited about QLM but seems there is no binding with Ruby, mail me at daddie88@gmail.com if you're interested