# Protecting against sql injection using activerecord

Tags: sql, ruby, activerecord

Following on the question [how can I use like query in ruby with sinatra?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24081696/how-can-i-use-like-query-in-ruby-with-sinatra/24081768#24081768) I have the following problem securing my sql from injection.Here is my method to make a query from the type string, it receives a v(alue) to search for and a k(ey) (=field) to look in.
After that the various selctions are joined by `selection.join(' and ')`

```
def string_selector(k, v)
  case
  when v[/\|/]
    v.scan(/([^\|]+)(\|)([^\|]+)/).map {|p| "lower(#{k}) LIKE '%#{p.first.downcase}%' or lower(#{k}) LIKE '%#{p.last.downcase}%'"}
  when v[/[<>=]/]
    v.scan(/(<=?|>=?|=)([^<>=]+)/).map { |part| p part; "#{k} #{part.first} '#{part.last.strip}'"}
  else
    # "lower(#{k}) LIKE '%#{v.downcase}%'" #(works)
    ("lower(#{k}) LIKE ?", '%#{v.downcase}%') #doesn't work
  end
end
```

But i get the error

```
selectors.rb:38: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting $end
from C:/../1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
```

What could i be doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's got to be a better way to do what you are trying to do if you are using ActiveRecord... However, if you need to support your `string_selector` functionality for some reason, I would at least use Arel:

```
def string_selector(k, v)
  tbl = Arel::Table.new(:test) # your table, or you could pass this in...
  condition = case v
  when /\|/
    vals = v.split(/\|/)
    first = vals.shift
    vals.inject(tbl[k].matches("%#{first.strip}%")) do |acc, val|
      acc.or(tbl[k].matches("%#{val.strip}%"))
    end
  when /<>/
    tbl[k].not_eq(v.gsub(/<>/, '').strip)
  when /\=/
    tbl[k].eq(v.gsub(/\=/, '').strip)
  else
    tbl[k].matches(v.strip)
  end
  tbl.where(condition).to_sql
end
```

Please note that `matches` will perform a case insensitive query for you (e.g., by using `ILIKE` in PostgreSQL).

Comment: thnx kardeiz but i get error "undefined method `matches' for #<Arel::Table:0x2c51490> (NoMethodError)" when i use matches on an Arel table, I tried making my query with activerecord hashes and methods but failed, there are many conditions to be combined on multiple tables so i use plain sql. I'm afraid that by using sql I no longer can protect against injection following the letters of the book but have found out that by using the LIKE injection is not working either, so I'll have to carry on without the extra protection I'm afraid

Comment: You can't call `matches` on an `Arel::Table`, it needs to be called on an Arel attribute. In my example `tbl[k]` is an `Arel::Attribute` for `k` on the defined `Arel::Table` `tbl`.

Comment: ah i see, sorry, in a small test this works, I'll try to integrate it in my query design